# Can the index (A, B) be used in ORDER BY A for WHERE A > const AND B = const. AND c > const

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT (..) FROM db WHERE A > const. AND B = const. AND C > const. ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT const.
```

I definitely need a multi column index (A, B) as the A filter is not strong enough. But can this index be used in the `ORDER BY A` statement or does this need a (A, B, C) index?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the index  index (A, B)   is used  both  in your where   and in your order  by

see this  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

> The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the
>   index exactly, as long as all unused portions of the index and all
>   extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause. The
>   following queries use the index to resolve the ORDER BY part:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM t1
>   ORDER BY key_part1,key_part2,... ;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In this query:

```
SELECT (..)
FROM db
WHERE A = const. AND B = const. AND C = const.
ORDER BY A DESC
LIMIT const.
```

The `ORDER BY` is redundant -- you have explicitly stated that `A` is a constant.  You should remove the `ORDER BY` entirely from the query.

This is not an explicit example in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html), so I am not sure if MySQL is smart enough to use the index in this case.  MySQL is not necessarily going to optimize a query that has an unnecessary `ORDER BY`, so your best bet is to check the execution plan.

To be clear, the following should use the index for the `ORDER BY`:

```
WHERE A = const.
ORDER BY B
LIMIT const.
```

Or:

```
WHERE A = const. AND B = const.
ORDER BY C
LIMIT const.
```

EDIT:

(Which is why I answered as above)

If your condition is `a > const` *with other conditions*, then I don't think an index will be used.  You *could* do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT (..)
      FROM db
      WHERE A > const.
      ORDER BY A DESC
     ) a
WHERE B = const. AND C > const. 
LIMIT const.
```

This *should* use the index for the subquery.  The filtering then takes place afterwards (not using the index, but you need the datapages anyway for the `select . . .`.

Note:  I don't like this solution.  In SQL in general a subquery should not be assumed to be in a particular order.  However, it does work in MySQL and is essentially documented as working because MySQL materializes subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I actually have the condition A > const. I corrected my post.